# Save print document or print preview as image in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, vb.net-2010, printdocument

I want to save a print preview to an image file in vb.net.
So far my application generates a print preview with the text the user provides and it prints, but I want to save the printed image to my computer.
I have already googled and saw lots of answers, like [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/70901-save-printdocument-to-image/)

But somehow it's not working for me. Any help will be appreciate.

My current code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    PrintDocument1.Print()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim fornt1 As New Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), PictureBox1.Image.Size)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(PictureBox1.Image, rect) 'Draw Image
    e.Graphics.DrawString(RichTextBox1.Text, fornt1, Brushes.LightBlue, 500, 500)
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved Your Problem.

Here Is How Your Form Should Look Like:
[image]

and here is the Code :

```
Public Class Form1
Dim BMP As New Drawing.Bitmap(322, 332)
Dim Graph As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BMP)

Private Sub PrintBUT_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PrintBUT.Click
    Graph.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
    Graph.DrawString(RichTextBox1.Text, RichTextBox1.Font, Brushes.Black, 5, 5)
    PictureBox1.Image = BMP
End Sub

Private Sub SaveBUT_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveBUT.Click
    Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    Try
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "JPEG |*.jpeg"
        If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            PictureBox1.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

I hope this code was useful to you. :)